# setters won't get the new getters values

Tags: php, oop

I am trying following script but it doesn't seem to pick up new value processed bt `__set` i am trying to read through [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php-for-beginners--net-12762) article to get hold of OOP working my way up to magento. Is there is something missing?

```
class MyClass{
public $name = "Mike";

        private function __setProperty($newval){
            $this->name = $newval;
        }

        public function __getProperty(){
            return $this->name;
        }
    }
$obj = new MyClass;

//var_dump($obj);
echo $obj->name;
$obj->getProperty("Angela");
echo $obj->getProperty();
```

Comment: That tutorial you said you are learning from, specifically states the `setProperty`... `$obj = new MyClass;
 
echo $obj->getProperty(); // Get the property value
 
$obj->setProperty("I'm a new property value!"); // Set a new one
 
echo $obj->getProperty(); // Read it out again to show the change`. You're using `getProperty` instead. You didn't follow that tutorial *"to a T"*.

Comment: Prevent declaring method names starting with `__`. They are normaly preserved for PHP magic methods. The usage you are using here has no relevance to `__set` and `__get` at all.

Comment: Your use of `__` for methods is weird (And wrong, `__` prefixed methods tend to be magic methods). The setter is never called (and declared private). At no point are you actually actually setting the property...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistake here `$obj->getProperty("Angela");` you need to use `setProperty`

```
echo $obj->name;
$obj->setProperty("Angela");
echo $obj->getProperty();
```

and your function are `public` not `private`

And i think you want __set, here an exemple of [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set):

```
public function __set($name, $value)
{
    $this->data[$name] = $value;
}
```

Comment: Pretty pointless to use magic methods for properties that are declared `public`

Comment: Yes, but on the request he speak about `__set`, its why he misunderstand when he mix `__set` and `__getProperty` instead of `getProperty`

Answer (score 4):

1. You try to set the property to "Angela" but use the `getProperty()` method instead of `setProperty()`.
2. Your property names start with two underscores (`__`) but you call the method without (i.e. instead of `$obj->setProperty()` you should use `$obj->__setProperty()` or change the method names)
3. Your `setProperty()` method is `private`, which means that it can't be accessed outside of the class. The method needs to be `public` if you want it to be accessible at the object level.

---

Change your code to:

```
class MyClass{
    public $name = "Mike";

    public function setProperty($newval){
        $this->name = $newval;
    }

    public function getProperty(){
        return $this->name;
    }
}
$obj = new MyClass;

//var_dump($obj);
echo $obj->name;
$obj->setProperty("Angela");
echo $obj->getProperty();
```

This will output:

> MikeAngela